# Why does mongodb has ObjectID as string?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

As a general understanding, numeric operations are faster than string operations. It is faster to compute `2 < 5` than `"hello" < "world"`.
Also, since the length of the _id is 12. If it is stored as a string where a character can take 2 bytes and thus the entire string would take 24 bytes. However a number of 8 bytes can very easily store this value of 12 digits. Basically, a number type would take lesser space.
So with these logics, why does mongodb store _id as string type ObjectIDs and not numeric ObjectID?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is incorrect.

It is much better than Strings. It just takes 12 bytes in memory as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

[Java implementation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/bson/src/main/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java) for the same.

[Refer toHexString](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/bson/src/main/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java) in the github link, that's what returned to you when you ask for String. It actually takes 24bytes whereas ObjectId takes only 12bytes.

Comment: One point answered, still, why does it have to be string when numeric operations are faster?

Comment: It is not at all String.